# How to GET data for multiple profile_ids in Google Analytics Reporting API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

Is there a way to fetch information for multiple `ids` in a single GA Reporting API query? See here for reference to the tool I am using: http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

Comment: The **R language** and the **RGoogleAnalytics** package might help you with that. Here is an example of querying multiple GA Views at once using a for loop in R. http://www.analyticsforfun.com/2015/05/query-multiple-google-analytics-view.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tthe Google Analtyics core Reporting API is a little confusing.  [Core Reporting API - Reference Guide - Ids](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#ids) calls the Query Parameter ids but it is in fact singular.  You can only send one id at a time.

Anwser: There is no way to send more then one view (profile_id) to the Core reporting api as a single request.   You will need to loop over your request and send it multiple times.

Example:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:34896749&dimensions=ga:date&metrics=ga:entrances&start-date=2014-05-12&end-date=2014-05-22&oauth_token={OauthToken}
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:34896744&dimensions=ga:date&metrics=ga:entrances&start-date=2014-05-12&end-date=2014-05-22&oauth_token={OauthToken}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's unfortunate. I will need to make multiple requests in a loop then.

Comment: Is there a limit for number of api calls per day?

Comment: 10000 per profile per day.   Default is 50000 calls per project client id per day